# Correctness of proof that the commutative operation * on a binary structure is a structural property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Here is what I have as a proof for now. Can you tell me where I need to edit it and or how it should be instead?

Let  and  be two arbitrary binary structures with an isomorphism f: S->T. Assume * is commutative. 
Then we have that f(a*b)=f(a)*f(b) for all a, b in S
Due to commutativity f(b*a)=f(b)*f(a)=f(a*b)
From this we have proven that the operation is preserved. 
Since f maps S bijectively to T the function is an isomorphic operation and therefore a structural property

Comment: What is your definition of "structural property"? See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108940/show-that-an-operation-being-commutative-is-a-structural-property

Answer (score 0):

You have all the necessary elements in your proof, but it lacks readability and precision.

I would write: "Proof that *any* commutative operator on a binary structure is a structural property". Then I would define $*$ to be a commutative operation on elements of $S$, and proceed to demonstrate how $*$ is a structural property.